# I lost admin access in Azure Active Directory. What should I do?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

Apparently, I have removed myself from Administrators. Besides, there are no more admins in the AD. How can I restore my access? Or am I missing something?

What I've tried:

1. Go to AD -> Properties -> Access management for Azure resources. It is greyed out so I can not turn it on.
2. Go to AD -> Users. I can see myself with the role "Member" with no means to change that.
3. Go to AD -> Roles and administrators -> Application administrator -> Assignments. Got "No role assignments found" meaning that there is nobody assigned to that role.
4. AD -> Roles and administrators -> Global administrator -> Assignments. I've got "Microsoft.Office365Portal" but I have no idea what it is and how to log in as that Office365Portal user. I am not even an Office 365 user.

Comment: I think the only possible thing to do is open a support ticket

Answer (score 2):

If you have an unmanaged tenant, can perform an internal admin takeover in which you verify ownership of the domain and become Global Admin.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/domains-admin-takeover

Comment: An _unmanaged tenant_ is one which is created automatically on behalf of users, and which can be reclaimed. The OP states the he lost admin access, so this implies that at one point he had such access and thus the tenant cannot be reclaimed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to elevate your access:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/elevate-access-global-admin

If your subscription was created by CSP you might ask them to help.

Microsoft recommends having at least two break-glass emergency accounts for situations like this.

Comment: I have no subscription. Nor I can create one. Elevating access is an option for If you  Global Administrator already. I am glad that recommendation of the Microsoft is there, however, it is too late to follow it unfortunately.